# How come I have to `source ~/.profile` every time I launch a new terminal?

Tags: linux, macos, terminal

When I launch my terminal and I do

```
node --version
```

I get `2. w/e`

Then I try to do `nvm use 5.3.0` and it says `nvm: command not found`

So then I have to

```
source ~/.profile
```

Then I can use the `nvm` command, but as well, the node version gets set back to `2. w/e` every time I close the terminal doesn’t seem to save, how can I fix this this?

Comment: Supply more details: what shell? What terminal emulator? Why did you tag this with both `linux` and `osx`? What OS and version are you experiencing this on?